# Selector in Smartpanel giving error '<Selector Name> cannot be found in the system.'

Tags: acumatica

I have a smartpanel with two different selectors with data fields called KnownContributor and NewContributor. When I pick a selection from either selector, NewContributor for example, the selector highlights red and I get the error message 'NewContributor cannot be found in the system.' I have the selector clearly defined and this exists on a page with multiple smart panels defined in the same exact manner with selectors also defined in the same exact manner other than the PXSelector's Search syntax.

Here is the before and after a selection is made images:
[image]

[image]

Here is all of the code:

ASPX:

```
<px:PXSmartPanel AutoReload="false" runat="server" DesignView="content" Height="225px" Width ="350px" ID="spSetOnlineCheck" LoadOnDemand="true" AutoRepaint="true" ShowAfterLoad="true" CaptionVisible="true" Caption="Set Online Check Contributor" Key="SetOnlineCheckPopup">
    <px:PXFormView Height="225px" Width="100%" SkinID="Transparent" DataSourceID="ds" runat="server" ID="fvOnlineCheck" DataMember="SetOnlineCheckPopup">
        <Template>
            <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" ID="lrPopupCheck" StartColumn="True"></px:PXLayoutRule>
            <px:PXPanel Width="100%" Height="200px" runat="server" ID="pnlOnlineCheck">
                <px:PXLabel Width="100%" Height="50px" runat="server" ID="lblOnlineCheck" Text="Pick contributor to be associated with this online check."></px:PXLabel>
                <px:PXSelector FilterByAllFields="true" CommitChanges="True" runat="server" ID="selKnown" DataField="KnownContributor"></px:PXSelector>
<px:PXLabel runat="server" ID="CstLabel9" Size="10px" ></px:PXLabel>
<px:PXSelector CommitChanges="True" runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector10" DataField="NewContributor" ></px:PXSelector>
                <px:PXLabel runat="server"  ID="lblOnlineBankSpace" Height="50px"></px:PXLabel>
                <px:PXButton runat="server" ID="AddContributorOK" Text="OK" DialogResult="OK"></px:PXButton>
            <px:PXButton runat="server" ID="AddContributorCancel" Text="Cancel" DialogResult="Cancel"></px:PXButton></px:PXPanel>
        </Template>
    </px:PXFormView>
</px:PXSmartPanel>
```

DAC:

```
[Serializable]
public class SetBankCheckPopup : IBqlTable
{
    [PXInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "BankID")]
    public int? BankID { get; set; }
    public class bankdID : IBqlField { }

    [PXInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Known Contributors")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<CustomerPaymentMethod.bAccountID>),
        new Type[]{
            typeof(CustomerPaymentMethod.bAccountID)
        })]
    //[PXSelector(typeof(Search5<CustomerPaymentMethod.bAccountID, InnerJoin<CustomerPaymentMethodDetail,
    //    On<CustomerPaymentMethod.pMInstanceID, Equal<CustomerPaymentMethodDetail.pMInstanceID>,
    //        And<CustomerPaymentMethodDetail.detailID, Equal<C1>,
    //    And<CustomerPaymentMethodDetail.value, Equal<Current<SetBankCheckPopup.routeNbr>>>>>,
    //    InnerJoin<CFBSCustomerPaymentMethodDetailCopy, On<CFBSCustomerPaymentMethodDetailCopy.pMInstanceID, Equal<CustomerPaymentMethod.pMInstanceID>,
    //       And<CFBSCustomerPaymentMethodDetailCopy.detailID, Equal<C2>,
    //        And<CFBSCustomerPaymentMethodDetailCopy.value, Equal<Current<SetBankCheckPopup.acctNbr>>>>>,
    //        InnerJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<CustomerPaymentMethod.bAccountID>>>>>, Aggregate<GroupBy<CustomerPaymentMethod.bAccountID>>>),
    //    new Type[]
    //    {
    //        typeof(BAccount.acctCD),
    //        typeof(BAccount.acctName)
    //    },
    //    ValidateValue =false
    //    )]
    public int? KnownContributor { get; set; }
    public class knownContributor : IBqlField { }

    [PXInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "New Contributor")]
    //[PXSelector(typeof(Search<CustomerPaymentMethod.bAccountID>),
    //    new Type[]{
    //        typeof(CustomerPaymentMethod.bAccountID)
    //    })]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search5<CustomerPaymentMethod.bAccountID, InnerJoin<CustomerPaymentMethodDetail,
        On<CustomerPaymentMethod.pMInstanceID, Equal<CustomerPaymentMethodDetail.pMInstanceID>,
            And<CustomerPaymentMethodDetail.detailID, Equal<C1>,
        And<CustomerPaymentMethodDetail.value, NotEqual<Current<SetBankCheckPopup.routeNbr>>>>>,
        InnerJoin<CFBSCustomerPaymentMethodDetailCopy, On<CFBSCustomerPaymentMethodDetailCopy.pMInstanceID, Equal<CustomerPaymentMethod.pMInstanceID>,
           And<CFBSCustomerPaymentMethodDetailCopy.detailID, Equal<C2>,
            And<CFBSCustomerPaymentMethodDetailCopy.value, NotEqual<Current<SetBankCheckPopup.acctNbr>>>>>,
            InnerJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<CustomerPaymentMethod.bAccountID>>>>>, Aggregate<GroupBy<CustomerPaymentMethod.bAccountID>>>),
                    new Type[]
        {
            typeof(CustomerPaymentMethod.bAccountID),
            typeof(BAccount.acctName)
        },
        DescriptionField = typeof(BAccount.acctName),
        SubstituteKey = typeof(BAccount.bAccountID),
        ValidateValue = false
        )]
    public int? NewContributor { get; set; }
    public class newContributor : IBqlField { }

    [PXString()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Route Nbr")]
    public string RouteNbr { get; set; }
    public class routeNbr : IBqlField { }

    [PXString()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Acct Nbr")]
    public string AcctNbr { get; set; }
    public class acctNbr : IBqlField { }
}
```

Action Button:

```
public PXAction<CFBSContributionDetail> SetOnlineCheck;
[PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Set Online Check")]
protected void setOnlineCheck()
{
    //NOTE: All online checks come in under the same bank number and routing number. There is no way to distinguish who's check it is without looking at the check.
    SetOnlineCheckPopup.Current.RouteNbr = CurrentDocument.Current.RouteNbr;
    SetOnlineCheckPopup.Current.AcctNbr = CurrentDocument.Current.AcctNbr;

    if (SetOnlineCheckPopup.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (SetOnlineCheckPopup.Current.KnownContributor == null && SetOnlineCheckPopup.Current.NewContributor == null)
            return;
        CFBSContributionDetail row = CurrentDocument.Current;

        //Create payment record for customer with bank and routing number
        if (SetOnlineCheckPopup.Current.KnownContributor == null)
        {
            CreateNewCustomerPaymentMethod(row, SetOnlineCheckPopup.Current.NewContributor);
            row.ContributorID = SetOnlineCheckPopup.Current.NewContributor;
        }
        else
        {
            row.ContributorID = SetOnlineCheckPopup.Current.KnownContributor;
        }

    }
}
```

NOTE: In the DAC, the first DAC I just included all cusotmers where in the 2nd DAC I left in the original filtering I'd like to have. I did this just to prove that it isn't the PXSelector(Search) section causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it was because the selector was based on CustomerPaymentMethod. I switched it to be based on BAccount ([PXSelector(typeof